# how to fetch data with react-app from node,express-server, when react-app is called from server

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express

I have a react-app which is called from my node-server. But the react-app also fetches data from the server. The problem is, that the react-app is just able to fetch data from the server, when this code is deleted:

```
app.get('/*', function (req, res) {
res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '../build', 'index.html'));
```

})

Because all requests are going to this app.get('/*'..), even when the react-app trys to fetch images from the server like this:

```
app.post('/images',express.static('images'));
```

Because all requests are going to the above function, so its not possible to fetch the images anymore.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: Are you fetching images with a POST request?

Comment: in the body is the name of the image. thats not the problem, its working like that.

Comment: is /images middleware above the /* one in code?

Comment: ah no thats a mistake, im using get. just wrote it wrong here

Comment: i tried both.  @Lawrence

Answer (score 0):

You should use

```
app.use(express.static('images'))
```

Instead of adding a route. Then you need to add `static` as prefix to the http path. You could do the same with your react files.

check https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html

Comment: Thanks, but that doesnt work. It still just works when i delete the code, which calls the react app.